# TI SensorTag CC2650 | Data Logging when offline

Tags: logging, firmware

I'm new to using the TI SensorTag CS2650. I'm required to data log when the bluetooth is offline. I believe I can do so by modifying the firmware and using the flash ROM on board, however not so sure on how to implement it. Any help would be of great assistance.